# Apache 2.2.22 to 2.2.31 with weblogic

Tags: windows, apache-http-server

So, yesterday I attempted to upgrade on a Windows 2008R2 server, Apache that's the front end for a weblogic cluster. Two Apache servers.

I followed the upgrade guide and while apache seemed to work correctly for 5 or so minutes, it would stop serving pages, as well as stop writting any and all entries to the log file.

The steps I followed were:
Stop and uninstall the httpd service, stop the apache monitor.
Rename apache2.2 directory to 2.2_old
Unzip my apache binary directory and copy over the files in a new apache2.2 directory. 
I copied from the existing apache install all modules and config files and site pages. 
I installed the httpd as a service 
Pages would display for 5 or so minutes and then nothing, I'd recieve page could not be displayed errors and nothing would be written to our log directory file.

What I'm not sure of is the why behind this. I've never once messed with Weblogic and I'm not sure if it's a module issue with the wl_module I have from my existing install, or if this is something else all together.

Weblogic would come up completely and process pages, the webloader and portals all seemed to work and I didn't see anything config wise that needed to change since I was using the previous http-conf file.

No one here seems to know why this bizzaro issue happened either so we just backout the Apache install and are still using the old version of Apache.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed. The problem was two fold. 
1: The version and licensing of Weblogic that we have for some reason only allows for up to Apache 2.2.31 x86 version. 
2: There is a weblogic module that needs to be copied from the existing directory to the new directory.

Also, something I found interesting, cronolog doesn't exist any more in 2.2.31, it's been replaced with rotatelogs and you have to give time deliminators.